# Store not getting passed down to connected cellrendererframework

Tags: redux, ag-grid

I'm using the following components:
react v.16.5
react-redux v.6.0
ag-grid v.18.1

I'm using cellRendererFramework to display a custom component in  one cell of ag-grid.  However as soon as i make this custom component a connected component,

**Error:**

> Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(TestComponent)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React
>   context provider to  and the corresponding React context
>   consumer to Connect(TestComponent) in connect options.

the colDef in the ag-grid is as follows:

```
{
  field: "TestField",
  headerName: "Test Field",
  rowGroup: false,
  cellRendererFramework: TestComponent
}


// TestComponent.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class TestComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return(<div>Hello</div>);
  }    
}

export default connect()(TestComponent);
```

I've created the store and defined the provider at the Index.js level.
Is it that `cellrendererFrameworks` cannot be connected?

I came across this issue in another stack overflow post but there they'd said this issue has been resolved in react vers. 13?
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react/issues/88

Please note this is not for writing a testcase- i need the TestComponent to actually be connected.

Please could someone help with this as it seems a pretty fundamental bug that nested components are getting blocked from being connected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-more-details/#react-portals) and [lilbumbleber's response](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react/issues/142#issuecomment-461834867):

> With React 16 Portals were introduced and these are the preferred way to create React components dynamically. If you wish to try use this feature you'll need to enable it as follows:

```
// Grid Definition
<AgGridReact
    reactNext={true}
    ...other bindings
```

> If you use connect to use Redux, or if you're using a Higher Order Component to wrap the React component at all, you'll also need to ensure the grid can get access to the newly created component. To do this you need to ensure forwardRef is set:

```
export default connect(
    (state) => {
        return {
            currencySymbol: state.currencySymbol,
            exchangeRate: state.exchangeRate
        }
    },
    null,
    null,
    { forwardRef: true } // must be supplied for react/redux when using GridOptions.reactNext
)(PriceRenderer);
```

So, you could try adding those two:

1. Add `reactNext={true}` to `<AgGridReact/>` component
2. Change
   `connect()(TestComponent);`
   to
   `connect(null, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(TestComponent);`

Edit: This bug was fixed in [version 20.x](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react/issues/131#issuecomment-458483600)

Comment: Yep, tried that also but no luck.  Is there any additional import/install we need to do for that? Also tried upgrading react version to 16.8 as they said there was a release planned mid Jan 2019 but problem still persists.

Comment: This feature is [available from 20.x](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react/issues/131#issuecomment-458483600). You will need to bump the version as it seems.

Comment: Ok, thank you upgrading ag-grid-react to 20.x seemed to do the trick.  I ran the following: npm install ag-grid-community@latest ag-grid@latest ag-grid-react@latest --save and it installed following versions: "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^19.1.4",
    "ag-grid-react": "^20.0.0",

Comment: ag-grid-community seems to be a dependency of ag-grid-react ver.20.x, but it gives a warning that community needs to be 20.x.  Not sure why its installing only 19.x but for now, the upgrade along with your earlier suggestion seems to solve the problem

Comment: You save my life!